# Why does a=0; let a++ return exit code 1?

Tags: bash, ksh, arithmetic

Try it:

```
$ a=0
$ let a++
$ echo $?
1 # Did the world just go mad?
$ echo $a
1 # Yes, it did.
$ let a++
$ echo $?
0 # We have normality.
$ echo $a
2
```

Contrast with this:

```
$ b=0
$ let b+=1
$ echo $?
0
```

And this (from [Sirex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32250/why-does-a-0-let-a-return-exit-code-1/32251#comment43716_32251)):

```
$ c=0
$ let ++c
$ echo $?
0
```

What is going on here?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From `help let`:

```
Exit Status:
If the last ARG evaluates to 0, let returns 1; let returns 0 otherwise..
```

Since `var++` is **post**-increment, I guess the last argument *does* evaluate to zero. Subtle...

A perhaps clearer illustration:

```
$ let x=-1 ; echo x=$x \$?=$?
x=-1 $?=0
$ let x=0 ; echo x=$x \$?=$?
x=0 $?=1
$ let x=1 ; echo x=$x \$?=$?
x=1 $?=0
$ let x=2 ; echo x=$x \$?=$?
x=2 $?=0
```

Comment: good spot. i'm guessing ++a would act the same as += 1 then

Comment: Yep, that works.

Comment: For the record, this behaviour is the same on my ksh88 instance (although post-increment `let a++` does not work)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. - And I will not waste any more time and ask: "Why?"