# Trap, ERR, and echoing the error line

Tags: bash, shell-script, error-handling, trap

I'm trying to create some error reporting using a Trap to call a function on all errors:

```
Trap "_func" ERR
```

Is it possible to get what line the ERR signal was sent from? The shell is bash.

If I do that, I can read and report what command was used and log/perform some actions.

Or maybe I'm going at this all wrong?

I tested with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "ECHO $LINENO" ERR

echo hello | grep "asdf"
```

And `$LINENO` is returning 2. Not working.

Comment: You can look at the bash debugger script `bashdb`. It seems that the first argument to `trap` can contain variables that are evaluated in the desired context. So `trap 'echo $LINENO' ERR'` should work.

Comment: hmm just tried this with a bad echo | grep command and it returns the line of the Trap statement. But I'll take a look at bashdb

Comment: I'm so sorry... I didn't specify in my original question that I need a native solution. I edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, I borked the example line: `trap 'echo $LINENO' ERR`. The first argument to `trap` is the entire `echo $LINENO` hardquoted. This is in bash.

Comment: Didn't work. Still returned 2.

Comment: @Mechaflash It would have to be `trap 'echo $LINENO' ERR`, with single quotes, not double quotes. With the command you wrote, `$LINENO` is expanded when line 2 is parsed, so the trap is `echo 2` (or rather `ECHO 2`, which would output `bash: ECHO: command not found`).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, your quoting is wrong. You need single quotes to prevent `$LINENO` from being expanded when the trap line is first parsed.

This works:

```
#! /bin/bash

err_report() {
    echo "Error on line $1"
}

trap 'err_report $LINENO' ERR

echo hello | grep foo  # This is line number 9
```

Running it:

```
 $ ./test.sh
 Error on line 9
```

Comment: thanks for the example with a function call. I didn't know that double quotes expanded the variable in this case.

Comment: `echo hello | grep foo` doesn't seem to throw error for me.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @geotheory On my system `grep` has an exit status of 0 if there was a match, 1 if there was no match and >1 for an error. You can check the behavior on your system with `echo hello | grep foo; echo $?`

Comment: No you're right it is an error :)

Comment: Don't you need to use -e on the invocation line, to cause error on command failure?  That is: #!/bin/bash -e ?

Comment: Do you need to add `set -e` for this to work? I think so from my testing.

Comment: It is noteworthy that this only works for ERR traps; e.g. LINENO may always be 1 in an EXIT trap. c.f. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270623/169077

Comment: i like the way you still keep the trap a function... but just pass the lineno as a parameter. it keeps the code more readable easy... better than not using a function and then you have a 160 character line.

Answer (score 32):

You can also use the bash builtin 'caller':

```
#!/bin/bash

err_report() {
  echo "errexit on line $(caller)" >&2
}

trap err_report ERR

echo hello | grep foo
```

it prints filename too:

```
$ ./test.sh
errexit on line 9 ./test.sh
```

Answer (score 17):

> > Is it possible to get what line the ERR signal was sent from?

Yes, `LINENO` and `BASH_LINENO` variables are supper useful for getting the line of failure and the lines that lead up to it.

> > Or maybe I'm going at this all wrong?

Nope, just missing *`-q`* option with grep...

```
echo hello | grep -q "asdf"
```

... With the *`-q`* option `grep` will return `0` for *`true`* and `1` for *`false`*. And in Bash it's *`trap`* not *`Trap`*...

```
trap "_func" ERR
```

---

> > ... I need a native solution...

Here's a trapper that ya might find useful for debugging things that have a bit more cyclomatic complexity...

[**`failure.sh`**](https://github.com/bash-utilities/trap-failure/blob/master/failure.sh)

```
## Outputs Front-Mater formatted failures for functions not returning 0
## Use the following line after sourcing this file to set failure trap
##    trap 'failure "LINENO" "BASH_LINENO" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${?}"' ERR
failure(){
    local -n _lineno="${1:-LINENO}"
    local -n _bash_lineno="${2:-BASH_LINENO}"
    local _last_command="${3:-${BASH_COMMAND}}"
    local _code="${4:-0}"

    ## Workaround for read EOF combo tripping traps
    if ! ((_code)); then
        return "${_code}"
    fi

    local _last_command_height="$(wc -l <<<"${_last_command}")"

    local -a _output_array=()
    _output_array+=(
        '---'
        "lines_history: [${_lineno} ${_bash_lineno[*]}]"
        "function_trace: [${FUNCNAME[*]}]"
        "exit_code: ${_code}"
    )

    if [[ "${#BASH_SOURCE[@]}" -gt '1' ]]; then
        _output_array+=('source_trace:')
        for _item in "${BASH_SOURCE[@]}"; do
            _output_array+=("  - ${_item}")
        done
    else
        _output_array+=("source_trace: [${BASH_SOURCE[*]}]")
    fi

    if [[ "${_last_command_height}" -gt '1' ]]; then
        _output_array+=(
            'last_command: ->'
            "${_last_command}"
        )
    else
        _output_array+=("last_command: ${_last_command}")
    fi

    _output_array+=('---')
    printf '%s\n' "${_output_array[@]}" >&2
    exit ${_code}
}
```

... and an example usage script for exposing the subtle differences in how to set the above trap for function tracing too...

[**`example_usage.sh`**](https://github.com/bash-utilities/trap-failure/blob/example/example_usage.sh)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -E -o functrace

## Optional, but recommended to find true directory this script resides in
__SOURCE__="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [[ -h "${__SOURCE__}" ]]; do
    __SOURCE__="$(find "${__SOURCE__}" -type l -ls | sed -n 's@^.* -> \(.*\)@\1@p')"
done
__DIR__="$(cd -P "$(dirname "${__SOURCE__}")" && pwd)"


## Source module code within this script
source "${__DIR__}/modules/trap-failure/failure.sh"

trap 'failure "LINENO" "BASH_LINENO" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${?}"' ERR


something_functional() {
    _req_arg_one="${1:?something_functional needs two arguments, missing the first already}"
    _opt_arg_one="${2:-SPAM}"
    _opt_arg_two="${3:0}"
    printf 'something_functional: %s %s %s' "${_req_arg_one}" "${_opt_arg_one}" "${_opt_arg_two}"
    ## Generate an error by calling nothing
    "${__DIR__}/nothing.sh"
}


## Ignoring errors prevents trap from being triggered
something_functional || echo "Ignored something_functional returning $?"
if [[ "$(something_functional 'Spam!?')" == '0' ]]; then
    printf 'Nothing somehow was something?!\n' >&2 && exit 1
fi


## And generating an error state will cause the trap to _trace_ it
something_functional '' 'spam' 'Jam'
```

The above where tested on Bash version 4+, so leave a comment if something for versions prior to four are needed, or [Open an Issue](https://github.com/bash-utilities/trap-failure/issues) if it fails to trap failures on systems with a minimum version of four.

The main *takeaways* are...

```
set -E -o functrace
```

- *`-E`* causes errors within functions to *bubble up*
- *`-o functrace`* causes allows for more verbosity when something within a function fails

```
trap 'failure "LINENO" "BASH_LINENO" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${?}"' ERR
```

- Single quotes are used around function call and double quotes are around individual arguments
- References to *`LINENO`* and *`BASH_LINENO`* are passed instead of the current values, though this might be shortened in later versions of linked to trap, such that the final failure line makes it into output
- Values of *`BASH_COMMAND`* and exit status (*`$?`*) are passed, first to get the command that returned an error, and second for ensuring that the trap does not trigger on non-error statuses

And while others may disagree I find it's easier to build an output array and use printf for printing each array element on it's own line...

```
printf '%s\n' "${_output_array[@]}" >&2
```

... also the *`>&2`* bit at the end causes errors to go where they should (standard error), and allows for capturing just errors...

```
## ... to a file...
some_trapped_script.sh 2>some_trapped_errros.log

## ... or by ignoring standard out...
some_trapped_script.sh 1>/dev/null
```

As shown by these and [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash) on Stack Overflow, there be lots of ways to build a debugging aid using built in utilities.

Comment: Very good answer! This should get a lot more up-votes. Excellent error tracing that actually enables debug

Comment: Can anyone help me understand why the "trap" line contains args like "LINENO" (the variable name) instead of "$LINENO" (the variable value). If I try something similar myself, passing the value appears to do the right thing.

Comment: Here's how to jump to the related manual sections `man -P 'less -ip "^\s+lineno"' bash` and `man -P 'less -ip "^\s+bash_lineno"' bash` at this moment I cannot remember why I chose to pass `LINENO` by name/reference instead of value... but I've a feeling it had to do with order of execution/expansion when the `trap` gets tripped vs when it is set.

Answer (score 16):

I really like the answer given by @Mat above.  Building on this, I wrote a little helper which gives a bit more context for the error:

We can inspect the script for the line which caused the failure:

```
err() {
    echo "Error occurred:"
    awk 'NR>L-4 && NR<L+4 { printf "%-5d%3s%s\n",NR,(NR==L?">>>":""),$0 }' L=$1 $0
}
trap 'err $LINENO' ERR
```

Here it is in a small test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

err() {
    echo "Error occurred:"
    awk 'NR>L-4 && NR<L+4 { printf "%-5d%3s%s\n",NR,(NR==L?">>>":""),$0 }' L=$1 $0
}
trap 'err $LINENO' ERR

echo one
echo two
echo three
echo four
false
echo five
echo six
echo seven
echo eight
```

When we run it we get:

```
$ /tmp/test.sh
one
two
three
four
Error occurred:
12      echo two
13      echo three
14      echo four
15   >>>false
16      echo five
17      echo six
18      echo seven
```

Comment: This would be even better using `$(caller)`'s data to give the context even if the failure is not in the current script but one of its imports. Very nice though!

Comment: I'm confused about  "set -e", I think this means exit on error. But you're handling the error. I cannot understand the purpose.

Comment: @TarekEldeeb - This isn't like catching an error in other languages, by the time that the error trap is called, the script is in the process of stopping. There's no option here to return to the command which caused the errexit to be invoked.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another version, inspired by @sanmai and @unpythonic.  It shows script lines around the error, with line numbers, and the exit status - using tail & head as that seems simpler than the awk solution.

Showing this as two lines here for readability - you can join these lines into one if you prefer (preserving the `;`):

```bash
trap 'echo >&2 "Error - exited with status $? at line $LINENO:"; 
         pr -tn $0 | tail -n+$((LINENO - 3)) | head -n7 >&2' ERR
```

This works quite well with `set -eEuo pipefail` ([unofficial strict mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/))

- any undefined variable error gives a line number without firing the `ERR` pseudo-signal, but the other cases do show context.

Example output:

```
myscript.sh: line 27: blah: command not found
Error - exited with status 127 at line 27:
   24   # Do something
   25   lines=$(wc -l /etc/passwd)
   26   # More stuff
   27   blah
   28   
   29   # Check time
   30   time=$(date)
```

Comment: Loved the mention about `set -euo pipefail`!!! But... is there any way to trap the undefined var case?

Comment: I don't know of a way to trap the undefined var error, which seems to be detected without firing this trap.  However, the built-in error message is quite clear and has a line number: `foo.sh: line 7: x: unbound variable`.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. That builtin message is enough for me. By the way, you might add `-E` to your "unofficial strict mode" so the trap also catches errors inside functions. My final strict mode became `set -Eeuo pipefail`

Comment: @MestreLion - updated answer to include `-E` in 'unofficial strict mode', good tip!

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by other answer, here's a simpler contextual error handler:

```
trap '>&2 echo Command failed: $(tail -n+$LINENO $0 | head -n1)' ERR
```

You can also [use awk instead of tail & head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279361/93540) if needed.

Comment: there's a reason the other answer provides context by way of 3 lines above and 3 lines below the offending line - what if the error emanates from a continuation line?

Comment: @iruvar this is understood, but I don't need any of that extra context; one line of context is as simple as it gets, and as sufficient as I need

Comment: Ok my friend,+1

Answer (score 1):

The trap is very useful for finding undefined variables and array elements. There are a couple of "gotchas":

1. Incremented variables

   `((i++))` post-increments. If `i` is zero, the return code is 1, triggering an apparent error.  See [Why does a=0; let a++ return exit code 1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32250/why-does-a-0-let-a-return-exit-code-1)

   Change to pre-increment `((++i))` and the problem goes away
2. Testing for unset array elements

   ```
   if [[ -z ${array[$element]} ]]
   then
   ...
   ```

   will report 'unbound variable'. The +_ syntax does not trigger this error

   ```
   if ! [[ ${array[$element]+_} ]]
   ```

   This form is not exactly easy to remember 8-{

Apologies for posting a comment as an answer: the "gotchas" can easily put you off using a trap so it seemed worth noting the ways to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

### first

```
# bash strict mode
set -Eeuo pipefail
# debug mode
# set -x
```

### second

```
function __error_handing__(){
    local last_status_code=$1;
    local error_line_number=$2;
    echo 1>&2 "Error - exited with status $last_status_code at line $error_line_number";
    perl -slne 'if($.+5 >= $ln && $.-4 <= $ln){ $_="$. $_"; s/$ln/">" x length($ln)/eg; s/^\D+.*?$/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g;  print}' -- -ln=$error_line_number $0
}
```

### third

```
trap  '__error_handing__ $? $LINENO' ERR
```

### sample output

```
which: no no-cmd in (/home/shm/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin)
Error - exited with status 1 at line 98
93     declare -A pse_pre_check_list;
94     pse_pre_check_list['yq is installed']='which docker';
95     pse_pre_check_list['mc is installed']='which docker-compose';
96     pse_pre_check_list['shell is bash']='grep bash <<< $SHELL';
97 
>>     which no-cmd
99 
100     declare -a pse_pre_check_order;
101     pse_pre_check_order+=('yq is installed');
102     pse_pre_check_order+=('mc is installed');
```

If we set `-E` it handles errors inside functions as well (see man bash)

---

For more you can read [bash-error-handling](https://github.com/shakibamoshiri/bash-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

Using @RichVel, this is how I use traps:

```bsh
  set -eEuo pipefail
  
  readonly LOG=".log"; echo "######### $(date) #########" >> $LOG
--trap 'echo "Failed. Exited with status $?. See $LOG" | tee -a $LOG; echo "Failed at ${LINENO}" >> $LOG; pr -tn $0 | tail -n+$((LINENO - 3)) | head -n7 | sed "4s/^\s*/>>> /" >> $LOG' ERR
```

Running this from a faulty script would give a nice log:

```bsh
set -eEuo pipefail

readonly LOG=".log"; echo "######### $(date) #########" >> $LOG
trap 'echo "Failed. Exited with status $?. See $LOG" | tee -a $LOG; echo "Failed at ${LINENO}" >> $LOG; pr -tn $0 | tail -n+$((LINENO - 3)) | head -n7 | sed "4s/^\s*/>>> /" >> $LOG' ERR

function bla(){
    blabla
}


echo a
if true; then
    if false; then
        echo;
    fi
    bla
fi
```

```
$ bash error.sh
$ cat .log
```

```bsh
######### Mon Feb 28 19:19:05 IST 2022 #########
Failed. Exited with status 127. See .log
Failed at 7
    4   trap 'echo "Failed. Exited with status $?. See $LOG" | tee -a $LOG; echo "Failed at ${LINENO}" >> $LOG; pr -tn $0 | tail -n+$((LINENO - 3)) | head -n7 | sed "4s/^\s*/>>> /" >> $LOG' ERR
    5   
    6   function bla(){
>>> 7       blabla
    8   }
    9   
   10
```