# Getting wrong $LINENO for a trapped function

Tags: bash, trap

I am writing a Bash script for myself to learn scripting. At some point, I need to add trap in order to clean unwanted directories and files if script is killed. However, for some reason I do not understand, trap calls the cleaning function - `clean_a()` - when script killed but `$LINENO` points to a line in the cleaning function itself, not int the function - `archieve_it()` - when script is killed.

Expected behaviour:

1. run script
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. trap caches <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and calls `clean_a()` function
4. `clean_a()` function echoes the line number, which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed. Let it be line 10 in `archieve_it()`.

What actually happens:

1. run script
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. trap caches <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and calls `clean_a()` function
4. `clean_a()` echoes an irrelevant line number. Say, line 25 in `clean_a()` function.

Here is an example as a part of my script:

```
archieve_it () {
  trap 'clean_a $LINENO $BASH_COMMAND'\
                SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT
  for src in ${sources}; do
   mkdir -p "${dest}${today}${src}"
   if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]] ; then
    error "Something!" 
   fi
   rsync "${options}" \
         --stats -i \
         --log-file="${dest}${rsync_log}" \
         "${excludes}" "${src}" "${dest}${today}${src}"
  done
}
clean_a () {
  error "something!
  line: $LINENO
  command: $BASH_COMMAND
  removing ${dest}${today}..."
  cd "${dest}"
  rm -rdf "${today}"
  exit "$1"
}
```

P.S.: Original script can be seen [here](https://github.com/numand/zahralik/blob/master/zahralik.sh) . Definitions and variable names are in Turkish. If it is required, I can translate anything to English.

**EDIT:** I change the script as best as I can do according to @mikeserv's explanation like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS4='DEBUG: $((LASTNO=$LINENO)) : '; set -x
archieve_it () {
  trap 'clean_a $LASTNO $LINENO $BASH_COMMAND'\
                SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT
  ..
}
clean_a () {
  error " ...
  line: $LINENO $LASTNO
  ..."
}
```

Now, if I run script with `set -x` and terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it prints correct line number as can be seen below:

```
 DDEBUG: 1 : clean_a 1 336 rsync '"${options}"' ...
```

However, in `clean_a()` function, value of `$LASTNO` is printed as 1.

```
 line: 462 1
```

Does it have something to do with the bug that is shown by @Arkadiusz Drabczyk?

**EDIT2**: I changed script just like the way @mikesrv recommended to me. But $LASTNO returned 1 as the value of the line when script was terminated (it should have been 337).

```
#!/bin/bash
PS4='^MDEBUG: $((LASTNO=$LINENO)) : '; set -x
archieve_it () {
  trap 'clean_a $LASTNO $LINENO "$BASH_COMMAND"' \
                SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT
  ...
} 2>/dev/null
clean_a () {
  error " ...
  line: $LASTNO $LINENO
  ..."
} 2>&1
```

If I run script and terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while rsync was running, I get this output:

```
^^MDEBUG: 1 : clean_a '337 1 rsync "${options}" --delete-during ...
...
line: 1 465
```

As you can see, $LASTNO's value is 1.

While I was trying to figure out what the problem is, I wrote another function - `testing` - using parameter substitution format `${parameter:-default}`. So script turned out like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS4='^MDEBUG: $((LASTNO=$LINENO)) : '; set -x
archieve_it () {
  trap 'testing "$LASTNO $LINENO $BASH_COMMAND"'\
                 SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT
  ...
} 2>/dev/null
testing() {
  echo -e "${1:-Unknown error!}"
  exit 1
} 2>&1
```

Now, if I run script and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I get this output:

```
^^MDEBUG: 1 : testing '337 1 rsync "${options}" --delete-during ...
337 1 rsync "${options}" --delete-during ...
```

337 points out the line when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, while rsync was running.

For another test, I tried writing `clear_a` funtion like this:

```
clear_a () {
  echo -e " $LASTNO $LINENO"
}
```

and $LASTNO still returned 1.

So, this means that we can get correct line number when script terminated if we use parameter substitution?

**EDIT3** It seems that I wrongly applied @mikeserv's explanation in EDIT2. I corrected my mistake. Positional parameter `"$1` should be replaced with $LASTNO in `clear_a` funtion.

**Here is the script which works how I want it to work:**

```
#!/bin/bash
PS4='^MDEBUG: $((LASTNO=$LINENO)) : '; set -x
archieve_it () {
  trap 'clean_a $LASTNO $LINENO "$BASH_COMMAND"' \
                SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT
  ...
} 2>/dev/null
clean_a () {
  error " ...
  line: $1
  ..."
} 2>&1
```

When the script is terminated, `trap` evaluates `$LASTNO` - first argument -, `$LINENO` - second argument - and `$BASH_COMMAND` -third argument -, then pass their values to the `clear_a` function. Finally, we print $LASTNO with `$1` as the line number which script is terminated.

Comment: Hi! About point 4 - "irrelevant line number" - on my system it always returns 1. Something changed in bash 4 - see [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-09/msg00021.html). What bash version do you have?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "echo $1" always gives me 1, not "echo $LINENO"

Comment: Hi, I use GNU bash, version 4.3.22(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu).

Comment: @mikeserv, sorry for inconvenience, my wrong. I corrected my mistake. Now it works how I want to work.

Comment: Bash also provides a `BASH_LINENO` array which is probably what you want, instead of just `LINENO`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're expecting `"$LINENO"` to give you the line of execution for the last command, which might almost work, but `clean_a()` *also* gets its own `$LINENO` and that you should do instead:

```
error "something!
line: $1
...
```

But even that probably wouldn't work because I expect it will just print the line on which you set the `trap`.

Here's a little demo:

```
PS4='DEBUG: $LINENO : ' \
bash -x <<\CMD          
    trap 'fn "$LINENO"' EXIT             
    fn() { printf %s\\n "$LINENO" "$1"; }
    echo "$LINENO"
CMD
```

#### OUTPUT

```
DEBUG: 1 : trap 'fn "$LINENO"' EXIT
DEBUG: 3 : echo 3
3
DEBUG: 1 : fn 1
DEBUG: 2 : printf '%s\n' 2 1
2
1
```

So the `trap` gets set, then, `fn()` is defined, then `echo` is executed. When the shell completes executing its input, the `EXIT` trap is run and `fn` is called. It is passed one argument - which is the `trap` line's `$LINENO`. `fn` prints first its own `$LINENO` then its first argument.

I can think of one way you might get the behavior you expect, but it kinda screws up the shell's `stderr`:

```
PS4='DEBUG: $((LASTNO=$LINENO)) : ' \
bash -x <<\CMD
    trap 'fn "$LINENO" "$LASTNO"' EXIT
    fn() { printf %s\\n "$LINENO" "$LASTNO" "$@"; }
    echo "$LINENO"
CMD
```

#### OUTPUT

```
DEBUG: 1 : trap 'fn "$LINENO" "$LASTNO"' EXIT
DEBUG: 3 : echo 3
3
DEBUG: 1 : fn 1 3
DEBUG: 2 : printf '%s\n' 2 1 1 3
2
1
1
3
```

It uses the shell's `$PS4` debug prompt to define `$LASTNO` on every line executed. It's a current shell variable which you can access anywhere within the script. That means that no matter what line is currently being accessed, you can reference the most recent line of the script run in `$LASTNO`. Of course, as you can see, it comes with debug output. You can push that to `2>/dev/null` for the majority of the script's execution maybe, and then just `2>&1` in `clean_a()` or something.

The reason you get `1` in `$LASTNO` is because that *is* the last value to which `$LASTNO` was set because that was the last `$LINENO` value. You've got your `trap` in the `archieve_it()` function and so it gets its own `$LINENO` as is noted in the spec below. Though it doesn't appear that `bash` does the right thing there anyway, so it may also be because the `trap` has to re-exec the shell on `INT` signal and `$LINENO` is therefore reset. I'm a little fuzzy on that in this case - as is `bash`, apparently.

You don't want to evaluate `$LASTNO` in `clean_a()`, I think. Better would be to evaluate it in the `trap` and pass the value `trap` receives in `$LASTNO` through to `clean_a()` as an argument. Maybe like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS4='^MDEBUG: $((LASTNO=$LINENO)) : '; set -x
archieve_it () {
    trap 'clean_a $LASTNO $LINENO "$BASH_COMMAND"' \
        SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT
    while :; do sleep 1; done
} 2>/dev/null
clean_a () { : "$@" ; } 2>&1
```

Try that - it should do what you want, I think. Oh - and note that in `PS4=^M` the `^M` is a literal return - like CTRL+V ENTER.

From the [POSIX shell spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03):

> Set by the shell to a decimal number representing the current sequential line number (numbered starting with 1) within a script or function before it executes each command. If the user unsets or resets `LINENO` , the variable may lose its special meaning for the life of the shell. If the shell is not currently executing a script or function, the value of `LINENO` is unspecified. This volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 specifies the effects of the variable only for systems supporting the User Portability Utilities option.

Comment: Thank you very much @mikeserv for your comment and effort.

Comment: @numand - I've just your edit and attempted to address it with my own. Does it help?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. But I found out something that can help us.

Comment: @numand what's that? and what do you mean it didn't help? it works fine for me

Comment: I edited my answer. I meant that I still got wrong line number. If my explanations are not clear enough, I will try to rewrite them.

Comment: I thank you very much. I really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 10):

mikeserv's solution is good but the he's incorrect in saying that `fn` is passed the `trap` line's `$LINENO` when the trap is executed. Insert a line before `trap ...` and you will see that `fn` is in fact always passed `1`, regardless where the trap was declared.

```
PS4='DEBUG: $LINENO : ' \
bash -x <<\EOF
    echo Foo
    trap 'fn "$LINENO"' EXIT             
    fn() { printf %s\\n "$LINENO" "$1"; }
    echo "$LINENO"
    exit
EOF
```

#### OUTPUT

```
DEBUG: 1 : echo Foo
Foo
DEBUG: 2 : trap 'fn "$LINENO"' EXIT
DEBUG: 4 : echo 4
4
DEBUG: 5 : exit
DEBUG: 1 : fn 1
DEBUG: 3 : printf '%s\n' 3 1
3
1
```

Since the first argument to trap, `fn "$LINENO"`, is put within **single** quotes, `$LINENO` gets **expanded**, **if and only when** EXIT it triggered and should therefore expand to `fn 5`. So why doesn't it? In fact it did, up until bash-4.0 when it was deliberately changed so that $LINENO is reset to 1 when the trap is triggered, and therefore expands to `fn 1`. [[source]](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-09/msg00035.html) The original behavior is still maintained for ERR traps however, probably because how often something like `trap 'echo "Error at line $LINENO"' ERR` is used.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "exit at line $LINENO"' EXIT
trap 'echo "error at line $LINENO"' ERR
false
exit 0
```

#### OUTPUT

```
error at line 5
exit at line 1
```

tested with GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Niklas Holm, and thank you for this valuable information.

Answer (score 2):

Getting `LINENO = 0`, instead of actual line number on script exit, can be fixed by trapping `ERR` (instead of `EXIT`).

In addition, add `set -E`, to ensures that those ERR traps get inherited by functions, command substitutions, and subshell environments. For example, this is how to print the function name that that causes script error, and its line number:

```
set -eE
trap 'echo "Error in function $FUNCNAME at line $LINENO"' ERR
```

Credits to: https://citizen428.net/blog/bash-error-handling-with-trap/

Answer (score 2):

this should do the job for the more recent versions of bash:

```
trap 'debug_line_old=$debug_line;debug_line=$LINENO' DEBUG 
trap 'catch echo EXIT rc=$? line=$debug_line_old' EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

So, quite by accident, I stumbled upon a way to get bash to properly display the $LINENO variable (e.g., in a DEBUG or EXIT trap) and give the line number like you would expect. It is much simpler than the other posted methods and doesnt require hijacking PS4 and STDERR. Im not quite sure *why* this works, though would love to learn why if someone else can explain it.

Basically, wrap what you want to run in a dummy function (call it, say, `_ff`), then run `source <(declare -f _ff)`, and then run `_ff` and any instances of `$LINENO` in `_ff` will actually give the line number.

EXAMPLE

```
    _ff() (
    trap 'echo "LINENO=$LINENO"' DEBUG;
    echo a
    echo b
    echo c
    echo d
    echo e
    echo f
    echo g
    )
    source <(declare -f _ff)
```

Now, running `_ff` will output

```
LINENO=2
a
LINENO=3
b
LINENO=4
c
LINENO=5
d
LINENO=6
e
LINENO=7
f
LINENO=8
g
```

Note: running `source <(declare -f _ff)` is the crucial bit...if you dont then you will just get `LINENO=1` for all the `$LINENO` statements.

Side note: This question is old, but it is the only place I found basically anywhere on the internet to give a working workaround for showing the correct $LINENO outside of ERR traps. As such, it only seemed appropriate to post this here.