# How to exit a shell script on error AND message the user?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a `/bin/foo` shell script file.

How to exit a shell script on error AND message the user?

If I simply use a `set -e` then it exits on error, but no commands running when it hits error, like sending a message to STDOUT or sending a mail.

The question: how to run a command if the shell script runs to an error?

SLES12, bash.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39623/330217

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function to message your user and use `trap` to have it execute when the script exits in error:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

on_exit () {
    echo "This script has exited in error"
}

trap on_exit ERR

echo 'yes' | grep "$1"
```

In use:

```
$ ./script.sh yes
yes
$ ./script.sh no
This script has exited in error
```

Comment: As if there wasn't a recent flurry of questions about set -e being completely unreliable.

Comment: @UncleBilly: I don't know what you're talking about but this Q/A has nothing to do with the reliability of `set -e`.   That is working exactly how it should.

Comment: Is it? What if the error happens inside a func? Would your trap be called or not? Also, think through whether/why do you need set -e at all.

Comment: It absolutely is.  It would work fine with a function as long as the function was built properly.  set -e is not really needed though when trapping err.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work on old sh too (instead just on bash):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
trap 'test $? -gt 0 && echo "This script has exited in error" >&2' 0

echo 'yes' | grep "$1"
```