# Using expr, $(()), (())

Tags: bash, shell-script, expr

In shell script we can substitute `expr $a*$b` with `$(($a+$b))`.

But why not just with `(($a+$b))`, because in any resource it is written that `(())` is for integer computation.

So we use `$(())` when there are variables instead of integer values do we? And what should we use instead of `$(())` when variables can receive float values?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149823/parenthesis-in-bash-arithmetic-3-2-1/149991#149991

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. For arithmetic, `expr` is archaic.  Don't use it.*
2. `$((...))` and `((...))` are very similar.  Both do only integer calculations.  The difference is that `$((...))` returns the result of the calculation and  `((...))` does not.   Thus `$((...))` is useful in `echo` statements:

   ```
    $ a=2; b=3; echo "$((a*b))"
    6
   ```

   `((...))` is useful when you want to assign a variable or set an exit code:

   ```
    $ a=3; b=3; ((a==b)) && echo yes
    yes
   ```
3. If you want floating point calculations, use `bc` or `awk`:

   ```
   $ echo '4.7/3.14' | bc -l
   1.49681528662420382165

   $ awk 'BEGIN{print 4.7/3.14}'
   1.49682
   ```

*As an aside, `expr` remains useful for string handling when globs are not good enough and a POSIX method is needed to handle regular expressions.

Comment: If expr is archaic what should we use instead of expr text : '.*'

Comment: If `s` is a shell variable, its length is `${#s}`

Comment: ${#} means a number of arguments and $(#s} means a number of characters of a variable does it?

Comment: Yes.  That's right.

Comment: @Stranger Many uses of `expr STRING : REGEX` can be written as `case STRING in PATTERN)`. `expr` is only useful when REGEX can't be expressed with shell wildcards.

Comment: @Gilles Good point.  I updated the answer to mention expr's regex capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

expr is old, but it does have one limited use I can think of. Say you want to
search a string. If you want to stay POSIX with grep, you need to use a pipe:

```
if echo november | grep nov 
then
  : do something
fi
```

expr can do this without a pipe:

```
if expr november : nov
then
  : do something
fi
```

the only catch is expr works with anchored strings, so if you want to match
after the beginning you need to change the REGEXP:

```
if expr november : '.*ber'
then
  : do something
fi
```

Regarding `(( ))`, this construct [is not POSIX](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Conditionals), so should be avoided.

Regarding `$(( ))`, you do not have to include the dollar sign:

```
$ fo=1
$ go=2
$ echo "$((fo + go))"
3
```

Comment: Many uses of `expr STRING : REGEX` can be written as `case STRING in PATTERN)`. `expr` is only useful when REGEX can't be expressed with shell wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following programs do more or less the same and they don't really differ. But that is not true.

```
#!/bin/bash 
s=-1000
for (( i=0; i<1000000; i++ )); do
    s=$((s+1))
done
echo "$s"
```

This is the correct way to implement this. The expression s+1 is evaluated by the shell and can be assigned to a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
s=-1000
for (( i=0; i<1000000; i++ )); do
    s=`expr "$s" + 1`
done
echo "$s"
```

Here the expression will be calculated by the program expr, which  isn't a shell builtin but an external Unix program. So instead of simply adding 1 and s a program must be started und its output must be read and written to the variable. Starting a programm needs a lot of resources and a lot of time. And this program is run 1000000 times. So the program will be much slower than the previous. Nevertheless the code works correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
s=-1000
for (( i=0; i<1000000; i++ )); do
    ((s=s+1))
done
echo "$s"
```

If the -e flag isn't set, the program will work correctly, too. But if -e is set when s=-1 and ((s=s+1)) is calculated. The expression s=s+1 evaluates to 0 and the exit code of ((0)) is >0 which is interpreted as an error by the shell and the shell exits the program.

The reason to set  the -e flag is that it is the simplest way of error processing: stop if an error ocurrs.

Comment: While the points about invoking external programs and the -e flag were correct, the code needed fixing. I edited the post: the for loops needed closing with a 'done', and the arguments of expr needed separating with spaces.