# How do I find the line number in Bash when an error occured?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, logs

How do you find the line number in Bash where an error occurred?

#### Example

I create the following simple script with line numbers to explain what we need. The script will copy files from

```
cp $file1 $file2
cp $file3 $file4
```

When one of the `cp` commands fail then the function will exit with **exit 1**. We want to add the ability to the function to also print the error with the line number (for example, 8 or 12).

Is this possible?

#### Sample script

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2
3
4 function in_case_fail {
5 [[ $1 -ne 0 ]] && echo "fail on $2" && exit 1
6 }
7
8 cp $file1 $file2
9 in_case_fail $? "cp $file1 $file2"
10
11
12 cp $file3 $file4
13 in_case_fail $? "cp $file3 $file4"
14
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398691/how-to-get-the-real-line-number-of-a-failing-bash-command

Comment: You could use `set -x` and/or `set -v` to trace what has been executed. Not exactly what you asked for but it will probably be helpful, too.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Rather than use your function, I'd use this method instead:

```
$ cat yael.bash
#!/bin/bash

set -eE -o functrace

file1=f1
file2=f2
file3=f3
file4=f4

failure() {
  local lineno=$1
  local msg=$2
  echo "Failed at $lineno: $msg"
}
trap 'failure ${LINENO} "$BASH_COMMAND"' ERR

cp -- "$file1" "$file2"
cp -- "$file3" "$file4"
```

This works by trapping on ERR and then calling the `failure()` function with the current line number + bash command that was executed.

#### Example

Here I've not taken any care to create the files, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, or `f4`. When I run the above script:

```
$ ./yael.bash
cp: cannot stat ‘f1’: No such file or directory
Failed at 17: cp -- "$file1" "$file2"
```

It fails, reporting the line number plus command that was executed.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `set -o functrace` in your example?

Comment: @jrahhali - takke a look at bash's man page on `functrace`. Allows any debugging enabled via calling to propagate to the function.

Comment: I'm familiar with it.  I was just confused because you weren't using any DEBUG or RETURN traps in your example, so thought I was missing some cool functionality of functrace.  But, it sounds like your reason for including it is in case the *caller* has a DEBUG or RETURN trap defined?

Comment: @jrahhali - correct, that's exactly why.

Comment: And if you later need to [disable the trap...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31202968/724752)

Comment: This does not appear to be working if you use functions; in that case, it will only print out the line where the function was called

Answer (score 20):

In addition to `LINENO` containing the current line number, there are the `BASH_LINENO` and `FUNCNAME` (and `BASH_SOURCE`) arrays that contain the function names and line numbers they're called from.

So you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

error() {
        printf "'%s' failed with exit code %d in function '%s' at line %d.\n" "${1-something}" "$?" "${FUNCNAME[1]}" "${BASH_LINENO[0]}"
}

foo() {
        ( exit   0 ) || error "this thing"
        ( exit 123 ) || error "that thing"
}

foo
```

Running that would print

```
'that thing' failed with exit code 123 in function 'foo' at line 9.
```

If you use `set -e`, or `trap ... ERR` to automatically detect errors, note that they have some caveats. It's also harder to include a description of what the script was doing at the time (as you did in your example), though that might be more useful to a regular user than just the line number.

See e.g. these for the issues with `set -e` and others:

- [Why does set -e not work inside subshells with parenthesis () followed by an OR list ||?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65532/170373)
- [bash -e exits when let or expr evaluates to 0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63166/170373)
- [BashFAQ 105: Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: does ${1-something} do the same thing as ${1:-something} ? I'm having trouble finding help on the - without the :

Comment: @kdubs, almost. `${var-default}` inserts the default value only if `var` is _unset_, `${var:-default}` also if it's _set to the empty string_. Try e.g. `f() { echo "a: ${1-foo} b: ${1:-foo}"; };` and call it as `f ""` or just `f` with no arguments. The POSIX text has a nice table of the different cases: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 (they use "null" for the empty string).

Comment: thanks. maybe my man page is out of date. couldn't find this in it. (or I could be blind...)

Comment: @kdubs, it's a bit hidden in Bash manuals. It says: "When not performing substring expansion, using the forms documented below (e.g., :-), bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null. Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is
unset." and then lists just the versions _with_ colons. [Here in the online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), the man page should have similar text.

Comment: thanks. I can see it now. I was just kind of glossing over that bit before. it didn't make sense before. now it does.

Answer (score 16):

Bash has a built-in variable `$LINENO` which is replaced by the current line number when in a statement, so you can do

```
in_case_fail $? "at $LINENO: cp $file1 $file2"
```

You could also try using `trap ... ERR` which runs when a command fails (if the result is not tested). Eg:

```
trap 'rc=$?; echo "error code $rc at $LINENO"; exit $rc' ERR
```

Then if a command like `cp $file1 $file2` fails you will get the error message with the line number and an exit. You will also find the command in error in variable `$BASH_COMMAND` (though not any redirections etc.).

Answer (score 3):

I decided to use the following, which includes a stack trace as `list of fns [list of line numbers]` if the script is in a function or the script line number otherwise. Thanks also go to previous answers, which I expanded on after some experimentation to handle both fn based and non fn based scripts.

```
set -eE -o functrace

failure() {
  local lineno=$2
  local fn=$3
  local exitstatus=$4
  local msg=$5
  local lineno_fns=${1% 0}
  if [[ "$lineno_fns" != "0" ]] ; then
    lineno="${lineno} ${lineno_fns}"
  fi
  echo "${BASH_SOURCE[1]}:${fn}[${lineno}] Failed with status ${exitstatus}: $msg"
}
trap 'failure "${BASH_LINENO[*]}" "$LINENO" "${FUNCNAME[*]:-script}" "$?" "$BASH_COMMAND"' ERR
```

So a simple command failure, looks like:

```
/tmp/b:script[32] Failed with status 1: cp fred john
```

And nested functions (where hello1 calls hello2):

```
/tmp/b:hello2 hello1 main[24 19 29] Failed with status 1: cp john 22
```

I report exit status for the odd times it gives you extra info, and unlike everyone else I want the full pathname of the script.

Further work will be needed to report exit due to signals.