# Why 'let' exits with code 1 when calculation result equals to 0?

Tags: bash, exit-status, math

I came across [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63166/bash-e-exits-when-let-or-expr-evaluates-to-0) question whose author had dealt with problem caused by:
`let x=1-1` exits with code 1.

According to [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf):

> If the last expression evaluates to 0, let returns 1;
> otherwise 0 is returned. (p. 56-57)

I'm not so familiar with bash nuances, so my question is "What is the reason of such behaviour?".
May be that's because 0 interprets like 'false'? It's a bit strange for bash-beginner like me that 0 as a result of arithmetic expression leads to an error exit code...

Comment: There is one possible usage of this behaviour on my mind: exit status 1 means FALSE, so `let ...` can be used as logical expression for `if`, `while` etc. Am I right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A zero integer value evaluates to *false* when used in a boolean context in most general programming languages.  This fact means you may have code like the following C code.

```c
c = 100;
while (--c) { /* do something while c is non-zero */ }
```

In the shell, an exit status of one evaluates to *false* when used in a conditional context.

```bsh
c=100
while let --c; do
    # do something while c is non-zero
done
```

Do you see the pattern here?  The `while` loop runs until `let` returns a non-zero exit status, which it does when `c` reaches zero.  The non-zero exit status does not mean "error" in this case, it only means `let` arrived at the result `0`.

Usually, though, `let` is replaced with `((...))` (an arithmetic evaluation) nowadays, as in

```bsh
c=100
while ((--c)); do ...; done
```

It's worth repeating that the `while` loops above do not care about `c`.  They care about the exit status of the `let` built-in utility and of `((...))`.

Comment: Note also how the `1 + 1 == 2` or `5 < 6` arithmetic expressions yield `1` and `6 < 5`, `1 + 1 == 3` yield 0, as you can check with `echo "$(( 1 + 1 == 2 ))"` or `(( a = 1 + 1 == 2 )); echo "$a $?"`