# Shell exit silently at arithmetic expression in for loop

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic

I have written a script to ssh remote hosts, execute commands, save output to files, and examine outputs. But it always exit silently at line `(( success++ ))` when iterate first item in array `workers`. If I replace `(( success++ ))` with `echo "process $worker"`, it will work fine and print all hosts. I cannot figure out what's wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
set -e
workers=('host-1' 'host-2' 'host-3')

output_dir=$(mktemp -d)

for worker in ${workers[@]}; do
  ssh $worker '
    echo abc
    echo OK
  ' > "$output_dir/$worker" &
done

echo "waiting..."
sleep 3
wait

success=0
regexp='OK$'
for worker in ${workers[@]}; do
  output=`cat "$output_dir/$worker"`
  if [[ "$output" =~ $regexp ]]; then
    (( success++ ))
  fi
done

echo "Total ${#workers[@]}; success: $success; failure: $((${#workers[@]} - success))"
```

Comment: Rather than reading the whole file into a variable, why not use `if grep -q "$regexp" "$output_dir/$worker"; then`? Or even `grep -c "$regexp" "$output_dir"/*` to get a count of the number of OKs. Also consider `success=$(( success + 1 ))`.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's a good advice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple example should explain why:

```
$ ((success++))
$ echo $?
1
```

The reason is that [**any arithmetic operation which produces a numeric value of zero *returns 1***](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32251/3645). I don't know what to say - Bash has gotchas enough for the whole world.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, This behavior is very confusing, even ... evil. It consumes people's lives.

Comment: That rule was created with [the expr utility](http://scosysv.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=expr&af=0&sf=0&of=UNIXv7&tf=2)(Linked Unix V7 manual): `… exit codes: 0 if the expression is neither null nor 0, 1 if the expression is null or 0…` So, perhaps, Unix is the one to blame.

Comment: `if (( .. )) ; ...` wouldn't work if `(( .. ))` didn't return sensible return values. Of course one might say that it should only fail if there is an explicit comparison (like `(( i++ < n ))`), but the implicit comparison against zero makes stuff like `while (( i-- )) ` work in the same way as in C and other programming languages.

Comment: @ilkkachu I understand the rationale, but this behaviour (in any language) is *not sane.* First, there are already ways to explicitly compare numbers, just use those. Second, the C language syntax is well known for lots of idiosyncrasies, and isn't exactly considered the gold standard. Third, the choice of zero is entirely arbitrary - why not every non-positive number instead?

Comment: @l0b0, telling boolean results apart from plain numbers would require typing, which the predecessors of C didn't really have, if I've understood my history lessons. (Neither has the shell's arithmetic.) From there it's just hysterical raisins. Though apparently, `(( ... ))` wasn't subject to `set -e` before Bash 4.1, and that's really what causes the problem here, not the return values of `(( ... ))` per se.

Answer (score 9):

It is the consequence of having `-e` set.
Any command with an exit code of 1 (not zero) will trigger an exit.

This script works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
(( success++))
echo "Still going 1 $success"
```

This doesn't

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
(( success++))
echo "Still going 1 $success"
```

#### Solutions

The simplest is to remove the `set -e` line.

If that is not an option, Use this:

```
(( ++success ))
```

Other alternatives:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
success=0
success=$(( success+1 ))
echo "still going 1 $success"

success=0
(( success=success+1 ))
echo "still going 2 $success"

success=0
(( success+=1 ))
echo "still going 3 $success"

success=0
(( ++success ))
echo "still going 4 $success"

success=0
(( success++ ))
echo "still going 5 $success"
```

Only the option number 5 will have an exit code of 1.

Other (more complex solutions for any value of variable `a`).
The first one uses the [(POSIX) colon (`:`) builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_16_01) to make it POSIX compatible.

```
: $(( a+=1 ))        ; echo "6 $a $?"   ## Valid Posix
   (( a++ )) || true ; echo "7 $a $?"
   (( a++ )) || :    ; echo "8 $a $?"
   (( a++ , 1 ))     ; echo "9 $a $?"
   (( a++ | 1 ))     ; echo "10 $a $?"
```

Comment: Those work when you're counting up from zero, but in the general case you'd need to squash the error exit with something like `(( something... )) || true`

Comment: A couple of solutions more added @ilkkachu . Even one valid in posix.

Comment: @Arrow, good point on the `: $(( .. ))` alternative. It doesn't actually even need the `||` to catch the error, since there the command that runs is `:` and it always succeeds.